# Google Map api markers Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I have a javascript that when runs, will build an XML file from my MYSQL table that I have setup. It works and it plots all the markers just as planned. Now, I am trying to tie in some dropdown filters. I have scoured through many examples, but cannot make it work for mine.

I added the variables for the drop downs like this:

```
var MeetingType = document.getElementById("Meeting_Type");
var type = MeetingType.options[MeetingType.selectedIndex].text;
var DayofMeeting = document.getElementById("Day_of_Meeting");
var day = DayofMeeting.options[DayofMeeting.selectedIndex].text;
var TimeofMeeting = document.getElementById("Time_of_Meeting");
var time = TimeofMeeting.options[TimeofMeeting.selectedIndex].text;
```

Now I am trying to create an array of my markers after they are created, so I can filter them like so:

```
for (var i = 0; i < placemarkers.length; i++) {
    if (placemarkers[i].type==type&&placemarkers[i].day==day&&placemarkers[i].time==time){
    placemarkers[i].setMap(MYMAP.map);
    }else{
    clearOverlays();
    mymarkers=[]
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the whole code. Can anyone help me get these values into an array? Mine is not working.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#map").css({
    height: 500,
    width: 600
});
var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(43.653823, -79.382843);
MYMAP.init('#map', myLatLng, 11);

$("#showmarkers").click(function(e){
    MYMAP.placeMarkers('include/xml.php');
});
});

var MYMAP = {
map: null,
bounds: null
}

MYMAP.init = function(selector, latLng, zoom) {
var myOptions = {
    zoom:zoom,
    center: latLng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
}
this.map = new google.maps.Map($(selector)[0], myOptions);
this.bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
}

var markerfilter = new Array();
MYMAP.placeMarkers = function(filename) {
$.get(filename, function(xml){
    $(xml).find("marker").each(function(){
        var name = $(this).find('name').text();
        var address = $(this).find('address').text();
        var address2 = $(this).find('address2').text();
        var Meeting_Type = $(this).find('Meeting_Type').text();
        var Time_of_Meeting = $(this).find('Time_of_Meeting').text();
        var Day_of_Meeting = $(this).find('Day_of_Meeting').text();
        var Open_Meeting = $(this).find('Open_Meeting').text();
        var Wheelchair = $(this).find('Wheelchair').text();
        var ASL = $(this).find('ASL').text();
        var Comments = $(this).find('Comments').text();
        markerfilter.push(marker);

        var MeetingType = document.getElementById("Meeting_Type");
        var type = MeetingType.options[MeetingType.selectedIndex].text;
        var DayofMeeting = document.getElementById("Day_of_Meeting");
        var day = DayofMeeting.options[DayofMeeting.selectedIndex].text;
        var TimeofMeeting = document.getElementById("Time_of_Meeting");
        var time = TimeofMeeting.options[TimeofMeeting.selectedIndex].text;

        // create a new LatLng point for the marker
        var lat = $(this).find('lat').text();
        var lng = $(this).find('lng').text();
        var point = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(lat),parseFloat(lng));

        // extend the bounds to include the new point
        MYMAP.bounds.extend(point);

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: point,
            map: MYMAP.map
        });

        var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        var html='<b><u>'+name+'</b></u><br />'+address2+'<br />'+address+'<br />'+Meeting_Type+',&nbsp'+Time_of_Meeting+',&nbsp'+Day_of_Meeting+'<br />Open Meeting:&nbsp'+Open_Meeting+'<br />Wheelchair Accessible:&nbsp'+Wheelchair+'<br />ASL:&nbsp'+ASL+'<br />Comments:&nbsp'+Comments;
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
            infoWindow.setContent(html);
            infoWindow.open(MYMAP.map, marker);
        });
        MYMAP.map.fitBounds(MYMAP.bounds);
    });
});
}
```

I have edited my code to reflect some changes I made but it is still not working.

Answer (score 0):

Try the jQuery Map Marker plugin if it helps, as it has good flexibility/ Below is the link for that

http://www.welancers.com/jquery-map-marker-plugin/

Comment: Is there not a way to use what I already have? Hate to start from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the rest of your code, the most direct way would be to

```
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: point,
        map: MYMAP.map
    });
    mymarkers.push(marker);
```